# .Lottie extension animations stop working after Webflow Code export

Tags: lottie, webflow, web-animations

I built this website on webflow - [Website](https://boat-watch.webflow.io/)

The website contains 3 scroll based animations which are .lottie extension
and 3 .json animations which are running on loop.

Upon Code export,
Only the .json animations are visible, .lottie animations do not load.

Exported website - https://metaminds.studio/Portfolio_watch/index.html